# How Much Overhead Does Web Sync Add?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication, merge-replication

I am running merge replication in SQL2012 using web sync.

Has anybody done any experiments to compare the performance of web sync to connecting to replication using a straight TCP/IP connection?

Just wondering if it might work to open up a port for a TCP/IP connection over the web and not to use web sync. If it could work is it faster?